# How to render dynamically fetched 3rd party component in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js, cdn

I am using an [emoji picker npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart#-built-for-modern-browsers). The package size is quite large ~25Kbs (minified + gzipped) which is why I want to dynamically fetch it only when required, to not increase my bundle size and initial load time.

If you scroll a bit in the docs, you'll find a way to dynamically fetch it using a CDN (snippet below). This returns an HTML element. The problem with React is that we `cannot render objects as children`. **I'd like to understand how to dynamically fetch this component and render it.**

```
import { Picker } from 'emoji-mart'
new Picker({
  data: async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emoji-mart/data',
    )

    return response.json()
  }
})
```

I also tried using [Next.js dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/improve/dynamic-import-components) but I think they only support local components as of now. The other solution I have in mind is to stringify the entire HTML and then dangerously set the inner HTML but that seems like a very hacky way to do it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If yes, the can you please share it as a solution?